# Who really ordered the creation of the Clone Army?

Tags: star-wars

It seems to me that the question is never resolved. Who ordered the creation of the Clone Army?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ordered it was, by Jedi Sifo-Dyas. Consult the Jedi Council, he did not.

<sub>[Script](https://web.archive.org/web/20111217191338/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/aotc-script.shtml)</sub>

> LAMA SU: Please tell your Master Sifo-Dyas that we have every
>   confidence his order will be met on time and in full. He is well, I
>   hope.
>
> OBI-WAN: I'm sorry? Master - ?
>
> LAMA SU: Jedi Master Sifo-Dyas. He's still a leading member of the
>   Jedi Council, is he not?
>
> OBI-WAN: Master Sifo-Dyas was killed almost ten years ago.
>
> LAMA SU: Oh, I'm so sorry to hear that. But I'm sure he would have
>   been proud of the army we've built for him.
>
> OBI-WAN: The army?
>
> LAMA SU: Yes, a clone army. And, I must say, one of the finest we've
>   ever created.
>
> OBI-WAN: Tell me, Prime Minister, when my Master first contacted you
>   about the army, did he say who it was for?
>
> LAMA SU: Of course he did. This army is for the Republic. But you must
>   be anxious to inspect the units for yourself.

---

Here's an explanation for a lot of the confusion and the vagueness surrounding this. The [draft script](https://sfy.ru/?script=star_wars_episode_2) refers to the person who placed the order as "Sido-Dyas", which is a twist on Sidious (Palpatine) and the story line strongly indicated the role of the Sith in both impersonating the Jedi and placing the order for the army. I couldn't verify the authenticity of this draft, but assuming it is true and moving forward:

#### 1:

> OBI-WAN: Then you must know Master Sifo-Dyas?
>
> ...
>
> JANGO FETT: Master who?
>
> OBI-WAN: Sido-Dyas. Is he not the Jedi who hired you for this job?
>
> JANGO FETT: Never heard of him.
>
> OBI-WAN: Really.
>
> JANGO FETT: I was recruited by a man called Darth Tyranus on one of
>   the moons of Bogden.
>
> OBI-WAN: No? I thought...
>
> TAUN WE: Sido-Dyas told us to expect him. And he showed up just when
>   your Jedi Master said he would. We have kept the Jedi's involvement a
>   secret until your arrival, just as your Master requested.

#### 2:

> OBI-WAN: (V.O.) ...I've never heard of a Jedi called Sido-Dyas, have you, Master?
>
> MACE WINDU: No. **Whoever placed that order was not a Jedi, I can assure you.**

#### 3:

> OBI-WAN: One more thing. Jango mentioned he was recruited by someone named Darth Tyranus. Any idea who that might be?
>
> YODA: With the forename Darth, a Sith he must be.
>
> MACE WINDU: **Our missing apprentice.** They are playing their hand at last.

Throughout the draft script, it is clear that the Jedi had *nothing* to do with it, going by Mace's tone and a Sith lord (most likely Sideous) impersonated the Jedi to place the order. It is also hinted that the Jedi knew (or deduced) that Dooku was Tryannus.

However, the following transpires in the movie:

> OBI-WAN: (V.O.) Yes, Master. They say Master Sifo-Dyas
>   placed the order for a clone army at the request of the
>   Senate almost ten years ago. I was under the impression he
>   was killed before that. Did the Council ever authorize the
>   creation of a clone army?
>
> MACE WINDU: No. Whoever placed that order **did not have the
>   authorization of the Jedi Council.**

Nothing in the movie indicates that the rest of the Jedi didn't know who Sifo-Dyas was.  Mace doesn't deny that it was a Jedi (as in the draft), instead looks at Yoda with a puzzled face and merely says that it did not have the authorization of the Council. The fact that he doesn't come to Sifo-Dyas' defense, implies that Sifo-Dyas was known to be somewhat of an odd-ball Jedi (not the Dooku kind, but the Qui-Gon kind) and that he might have done this is not surprising.

In the conversation with Jango, the word Darth is also dropped, instead referring to the person simply as Tryannus (Thanks to [BBlake](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1551/bblake) for spotting this, as the script linked above includes this. I have confirmed by reviewing the scene that the word indeed is dropped). I believe the overall vagueness comes from hasty (or deliberate) corrections to the draft.

Since the movies are G-Canon and generally take precedence over draft scripts, I'm sticking with Sifo-Dyas as being responsible. My interpretation as to the actual order of events is:

1. Sifo-Dyas (Jedi) orders the clone army for the Republic.
2. Darth Sidious learns of this and orders his apprentice Darth Tyrannus (Dooku) to intervene (possibly killing Sifo-Dyas) and collaborate with Jango to continue the production of the army, but with the change in motive unbeknownst to the Kaminoans.
3. Dooku, still a rogue Jedi, removes Kamino from the navigation maps to keep the Siths' plan a secret.

Point 3 above also agrees with Yoda's statement in the movie that only a Jedi could've removed it from the maps.

Comment: I know this is in the script, but I'm not sure if I buy it... It's heavily hinted that something else was going on...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto see my edit.

Comment: I don't think Jango Fett said "Darth Tyranus"  I believe the line was "I was recruited by a man called Tyranus"

Comment: @BBlake You're right. I just confirmed by watching my copy of the movie; the word Darth is omitted. I was going by a half-memory and the script (which I now realize is a third draft) to guide me. I'll update my answer accordingly in a while.

Comment: Well, the answer is great.. I have read it all, but I am unable to get who really ordered clone army..

Comment: Well, from Legends, the Jedi Sifo-Dyas commissioned it first, as he sensed a great coming darkness, and Darth Plagueis used this to manipulate him to order it as an army to held in reserve until needed (there was no Republic military before this). This is covered in the novel Darth Plagueis.

Comment: Obi-wan mentions that Sifo-Dyas supposedly died before he was claimed to have ordered the creation or the army, which seems to suggest to me that it he did not actually order the creation of the army himself.

Comment: update: Disney canon says [Dooku created the clone army.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku)

Comment: The existence of Sifo-Dyas as a Jedi who ordered the Clone army is confirmed in the sixth season of Clone Wars where Yoda discovers his light saber: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_One

Comment: Why would Sifo-Dyas order the clone army? What was he hoping to accomplish? Also, if Tyranus recruited Jango AFTER the clone army was ordered, then who was Sifo-Dyas planning on using as the original person for the Kaminoans to clone? It's of my opinion that Sifo-Dyas was working with Sidious and Tyranus an ordered it on their behalf with Tyranus recruiting Jango for it. Then either Sifo-Dyas or Tyranus (Dooku) deleted Kamino from the Jedi archives. Then Either of the Sith Lords killed Sifo-Dyas in order to cover their tracks.

Comment: @RedCaio it says he was "involved in the creation", while the army page says "the clone army was originally envisioned by Jedi Master Sifo-Dyas, who secretly commissioned the Kaminoan cloners to create an army for the Republic".

Comment: Why is Qui-Gon an "odd-ball" jedi?

Comment: Something you don't address in this answer is that Dooku, after Obi-Wan discovers his name of Tyrannus in the Clone Wars (Season 6 episode 10), claims that Sifo-Dyas agreed to help him, and that they created the clone army together. Is this ever confirmed, or debunked? - "Sifo Dyas understood. He saw the future. That is why he helped me" - https://youtu.be/KOVFlkhU-KI?t=18m50s (Apologies for the poor video link, I'm sure you can find a better one)

Comment: I wonder isn't a large clone army very expensive? How much deposit was paid by Sifo-Dyas? Was Sifo-Dyas super-rich since he can order an army without consulting the Jedi Council?

Answer (score 10):

It's unclear from the movie itself.  There are two options:

- Darth Sideous masquerading as Sifo-Dyas ordered the clones, and had Count Dooku erase Kamino from the Jedi archives while Dooku was still a Jedi and had access.
- Sifo-Dyas himself foresaw the war and placed the order for the clones.  In this case, it's unknown why someone removed Kamino from the Jedi archives.

It's heavily hinted that Sideous had Kamino removed from the archives, so as to keep his army a secret until the appropriate time.

Comment: The similarity of "Sifo-Dyas" and "Sidious" -- is it coincidental?

Comment: @artlung - probably just coincidence - the Jedi council reaction to Sifo-Dyas' name is that he was a real Jedi and that he died a while ago.

Comment: @artlung see my edit, which explains this.

Comment: Sifo-Dyas was a Jedi, yes. He was around when Dooku was still a Jedi (just before he left the Council). You learn more about him in the book Darth Plagueis

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sifo-Dyas), it *was* **Sifo-Dyas**.

> When the Sith were revealed to have returned during the Invasion of
>   Naboo in 32 BBY, Master Sifo-Dyas secretly commissioned the creation
>   of a clone army, placing an order with the Kaminoan government before
>   he was murdered by his friend, Master Dooku.

In the "Behind the Scenes" section of the above article, it says:

> "Sido-Dyas" [the original name for Sifo-Dyas] was originally only a
>   false identity for Sidious — Obi-Wan Kenobi claimed never to have heard
>   of him, and Mace Windu confirmed that there was no Jedi by that
>   name.

That corresponds to the draft & final script that @yoda mentions in his answer.  The article then goes on:

> His backstory was promised by George Lucas to be revealed in Revenge
>   of the Sith, but instead was explained in the lead-in novel
>   [Labyrinth of Evil](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Labyrinth_of_Evil).

So it seems there was meant to be more detail in the films, but Lucas left it out for whatever reason.