# What was Sidious' plan before the Clone Army showed up? Conquering the galaxy with the Separatists?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

At the end of Episode III, everything was great for Darth Sidious what with him having become the Emperor, Leader of the <del>Republic</del> Empire and its Clone Army. However, the latter was [ordered by Jedi Sifo-Dyas (unapproved by the Council though)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5776/769) and without it, the Republic might probably have ended up losing the war against the Separatists. So what was the original plan before the Clone Army showed up? The Republic surrendering just to learn *who* actually led them would probably not have been that convincing to its inhabitants and would probably have left the Jedi Council, his sworn enemies, intact.

Comment: Um... the clone army was the plan...

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? Apparently the only hint at Sith involvement into the commission of the Clone Army in the movies was that one quote from Jango Fett, which I _apologize_ for not having memorized by heart...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The clones *were* the original plan.

Note from the link you posted:

> OBI-WAN: Sido-Dyas. Is he not the Jedi who hired you for this job?
>
> JANGO FETT: Never heard of him.
>
> OBI-WAN: Really.
>
> JANGO FETT: I was recruited by a man called Darth Tyranus on one of the moons of Bogden.

Darth Tyranus was Dooku's Sith name, and Dooku was Sidious' apprentice.  QED.

Comment: That's merely from a draft-script, especially preceded by " I couldn't verify the authenticity of this draft"

Comment: "*I was recruited by a man called Tyranus*" is also in the movie, you know.

Comment: That's convincing then - especially since meanwhile I spotted [this](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Plan#A_secret_army), so indeed Darth Plagueis tricked the Jedi Sifo-Dyas into ordering the army. Still makes me wonder how they managed sneaking Jango in as the template without Sifo-Dyas noticing

Comment: I was almost going to change the transcript to that from the actual movie, until I realized the only difference is the changed name (Sido-Dyas became Sifo-Dyas).

Comment: @Plutor - yup, the draft status definitely shouldn't be seen as a minus-point here.

Comment: Hm, the [article I linked to](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Plan#A_secret_army) mainly refers to the book [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Plagueis), your quote seems to be the single hint at the Sith's plan including the Clone Army and not merely adapting to it... The quote makes me wonder though: How come Obi-Wan didn't bring this up with the Jedi Council? While the Clones were obediently loyal, the mere fact that Dooku _knew_ about them should have raised a big red flag...

Comment: Pretty stupid move from Tyranus to reveal his name...

Comment: @vsz - I'd need to rewatch AotC but my memory tells me that Jango Fett just said "Tyranus" (i.e *without* the "Darth") in the movie; if so there's nothing to link the name "Tyranus" with the Sith.

Comment: +1 Good answer. It could stand to be elaborated upon, especially now that we have Clone Wars s6 ep10 shedding some light on the subject.

Comment: @user8719 re: no link between Tyranus / Dooku and Sith - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/why-was-count-dooku-not-given-the-title-darth/9901#9901

Comment: @Zommuter This is definitely not the only hint that Sidious planned the whole thing. The whole trilogy is about how he planned the whole thing. Kamino was erased from the Jedi archives, for instance. Watch for clues if you watch the movies again.

Comment: @DCShannon I somehow considered that merely an indication that Sifo-Dyas did not want the Jedi Council to know about his plan yet. Yes, in hindsight all makes more sense with the Sith actually having planned this, but apart from Fett's quote which I missed, all seems more like circumstantial evidence. Then again, I _may_ have enjoyed 1-3 less than the original trilogy and thus not have rewatched them that often...

Comment: The clones weren't the original plan. Syfo-Dyas sensed the coming of the droid armies and commissioned the building of a clone army. After the infrastructure was completed and before the genetic jiggery-pokery took place, Sifo-Dyas' plan was uncovered by the Sith and he  was killed by them and his place taken by Dooku who continued to fund the project. He also provided the genetics from a (mean) bounty-hunter rather than a (noble) someone else.